# Regex to match strings containing letters, numbers and @

Tags: php, regex

I need a regex to match letters, numbers and possibly @ and . (They are not email adresses)

**Match:**

*mirs99milo* 
*kiapp98@dot.com*

**Non match:**

*Device*
*99987*

Sometimes, the string comes with a special character at the beggining, in this case the character should be skip and get the string, example:

*-mirs99milo*       -> Ignore the "-" and only match mirs99milo    
*-kiapp98@dot.com*  -> Ignore the "-" and only match kiapp98@dot.com

I already have this:

**(?=.*\w)(?=.*[A-Za-z])[\w]{1,10}**

which works perfectly fine, except for when the string has an "@"

https://regex101.com/r/bHUCaX/3

Any help is pretty much appreciate. Thanks.

Comment: Using `{1,10}` will prevent matching all of `kiapp98@dot.com`

Comment: Don't quite get your problem: So you want a regex that make sure you string: 1) must contain at least one digit and at least one alphabet 2) The string should contains only alphanumeric, `@` and `.` 3) Ignore first character in matching.  Am I right?

Comment: @AdrianShum yeah, just the point 3, is to ignore first character if it is not digit or alphabet. Anyways, this guy Nick posted the answer below. Thanks.

Comment: @dualdark what if the string is `@xyz` should that match? or what about `@xyz123`?

Comment: @dualdark as I have commented in his answer: his answer does not cater your first special character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add the `@` and `.` to the set of characters you do match:

```
(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Za-z])[\dA-Za-z@.]+
```

[Demo on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/bHUCaX/7)

Comment: You missed his "ignore first character" requirement: I believe the regex should be something like `(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Za-z]).?[\dA-Za-z@.]+)` instead (if you are using it as whole string match), or adding start-of-line/end-of-line anchors `^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Za-z]).?[\dA-Za-z@.]+)$`

Comment: @AdrianShum OP only wants to ignore that character if it's not digit or alphabet...

Comment: but it does not ignore: in your demo, you can see , in second line, it is simply matching from 2nd position.  To make it more obvious: add a line `-----test123` and you will see it still "match"

Comment: @AdrianShum agreed, but OPs question states, sometimes, there's **a** special character at the beginning. He doesn't say that there can be many. So although this regex is not anchored it does still meet his requirement.

Comment: I think you misunderstood: `He doesn't say that there can be many`: it shouldn't be many.  But your regex, as it is not anchored, does not really match-and-ignore the first single special character.  My example is just for you to compare with your test case with one single special character

Comment: What your regex effectively does is: find a string (within a longer string) which is composed by alphanumeric/@/dot .   To better demonstrate the problem, add a line `!@*(&afda1(@*Q$#)(213asdf` in your test case

Comment: @AdrianShum yes, which is exactly what OPs regex did, `"which works perfectly fine"`

Answer (score 0):

try this 
(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Za-z])[.@A-Za-z0-9]{1,20}

Comment: Could you please explain why you think this works? Only code as an answer isn't very helpful in most cases. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

As your requirement is not clear, here is my guess based on your question:

You want to make sure you string:

1. must contain at least one digit and at least one alphabet
2. The string should contains only alphanumeric, `@` and `.`
3. Ignore first character in matching

If it is the requirement, then you may use:

```
^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).?[\da-zA-Z@.]+$
```

This should allow you to verify if the input string is compliant to your format.

However, if you want to get the matching string in case it is compliant, and excluding the first special character if it exists, then you may do

```
^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).??([\da-zA-Z@.]+)$
```

Group 1 is what you need

Explanation of the regex:

```
^                                           start of line
 (?=.*\d)                                   look-ahead: at least a digit
         (?=.*[a-zA-Z])                     look-ahead: at least a alphabet
                       .??                  optional one any char, 
                                              reluctant match
                          (             )   matching group
                           [\da-zA-Z@.]+    1-or-more occurrence of 
                                               digits,alphabet, @ and dot
                                         $  end of line
```

[Regex101 Demo (Based on Nick's demo)](https://regex101.com/r/bHUCaX/8)